# How to reference types without import

Tags: typescript, jetbrains-ide, konvajs

I am not sure if this is a code, config or IDE issue. Using Jetbrains Rider.

I’m trying to use KonvaJS in non-modular JavaScript and it’s driving me crazy. The project I’m on is being rearchitected so while it will eventually comprise of modules, it does not currently.

I want to be able to use the Konva types, the IDE does not appear to automatically recognise them. I want to be able to declare a variable as such

```
let stage : Konva.Stage
```

In this circumstance Rider tries to auto import the Konva namespace.

```
import Konva from “konva”
```

Which does cause the IDE to recognise the types correctly, but once the typescript is compiled, I get a syntax error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

My script is not in modules, and it is probably important to note that I am referencing the Konva JavaScript file via a CDN and do not want it being compiled locally. I just want the IDE to recognise the types.

I saw this on Konva’s site for the commonjs:

```
const Konva = require('konva/cmj').default;
```

This also gives me `require is undefined`

However, when I the try to do `let stage : Konva.Stage` then the Konva namespace is unrecognised (though when in an expression it seems accessible). I’ve also tried to use  or just have the `.d.ts` files in the same directory to no avail.

I’ve had no issues with JQuery which is my only other external dependency.

If I don't import or require anything and just let the IDE be full of errors, the code actually runs perfectly after compilation

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

This is a .NET solution designed to be opened with Rider, however this could be done typescript exclusively. The relevant files are all in the `wwwroot` directory. `@types/jquery` and `konva` are the installed npm packages, though both libraries are referenced by local files/CDN in use.

https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0vOxLlg9JB0nJQpAbClrbg8hA#KonvaTest

Edit: I put a couple of my code files into modules and set everything up to use it. Things broke even more, again specific with importing konva! I have largely come to the conclusion that I will have to either write my own Canvas library (probably the quickest solution at this point) or write a type declaration file. Which is a tediously daunting task given how many files the konva typings are. If anybody wants to do it for $100 or so let me know

Comment: Can you use [the `import type` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) like `import type Konva from “konva”`? If not, could you produce a [mre] someone can drop into their own IDE to reproduce the issue?  Or maybe provide a link to a properly configured web IDE project that shows what you're seeing?

Comment: I could not get it to work, but it's been a few months since I tried extensively. 
Anytime I have 'moduleResolution' set to Node, the application breaks. In this case it adds an export{} to the bottom of the file which breaks at runtime (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export`). I can not have any import/export in the compiled Javascript.

It also has issues of not giving me errors in the IDE when trying to use it as a value. If my code is something like `new Konva.Group()` , I get the error `Konva' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.`

Comment: I have added an example project to the main post.

Comment: I can't quickly do anything with that example so I might not get to it.  If you could configure a web IDE project someone could just click on and see what's up, that would lower the barrier to entry and make it more likely that you get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konva types are designed for module usage. You may need to use some workarounds to make it work in other cases.

Probably the most simple one is to just modify default Konva types and use your own local version of it:

```js
// filters
import { Blur } from 'konva/lib/filters/Blur';
import { Brighten } from 'konva/lib/filters/Brighten';
import { Contrast } from 'konva/lib/filters/Contrast';
import { Emboss } from 'konva/lib/filters/Emboss';
import { Enhance } from 'konva/lib/filters/Enhance';
import { Grayscale } from 'konva/lib/filters/Grayscale';
import { HSL } from 'konva/lib/filters/HSL';
import { HSV } from 'konva/lib/filters/HSV';
import { Invert } from 'konva/lib/filters/Invert';
import { Kaleidoscope } from 'konva/lib/filters/Kaleidoscope';
import { Mask } from 'konva/lib/filters/Mask';
import { Noise } from 'konva/lib/filters/Noise';
import { Pixelate } from 'konva/lib/filters/Pixelate';
import { Posterize } from 'konva/lib/filters/Posterize';
import { RGB } from 'konva/lib/filters/RGB';
import { RGBA } from 'konva/lib/filters/RGBA';
import { Sepia } from 'konva/lib/filters/Sepia';
import { Solarize } from 'konva/lib/filters/Solarize';
import { Threshold } from 'konva/lib/filters/Threshold';

declare global {
  export namespace Konva {
    export let enableTrace: number;
    export let pixelRatio: number;
    export let dragDistance: number;
    export let angleDeg: boolean;
    export let showWarnings: boolean;
    export let capturePointerEventsEnabled: boolean;
    export let dragButtons: Array<number>;
    export let hitOnDragEnabled: boolean;
    export const isDragging: () => boolean;
    export const isDragReady: () => boolean;

    export type Vector2d = import('konva/lib/types').Vector2d;

    export const Node: typeof import('konva/lib/Node').Node;
    export type Node = import('konva/lib/Node').Node;
    export type NodeConfig = import('konva/lib/Node').NodeConfig;

    export type KonvaEventObject<EventType> =
      import('konva/lib/Node').KonvaEventObject<EventType>;

    export type KonvaPointerEvent =
      import('konva/lib/PointerEvents').KonvaPointerEvent;

    export type KonvaEventListener<This, EventType> =
      import('konva/lib/Node').KonvaEventListener<This, EventType>;

    export const Container: typeof import('konva/lib/Container').Container;
    export type Container = import('konva/lib/Container').Container<Node>;
    export type ContainerConfig = import('konva/lib/Container').ContainerConfig;

    export const Transform: typeof import('konva/lib/Util').Transform;
    export type Transform = import('konva/lib/Util').Transform;

    export const Util: typeof import('konva/lib/Util').Util;

    export const Context: typeof import('konva/lib/Context').Context;
    export type Context = import('konva/lib/Context').Context;

    export const Stage: typeof import('konva/lib/Stage').Stage;
    export type Stage = import('konva/lib/Stage').Stage;
    export const stages: typeof import('konva/lib/Stage').stages;

    export const Layer: typeof import('konva/lib/Layer').Layer;
    export type Layer = import('konva/lib/Layer').Layer;
    export type LayerConfig = import('konva/lib/Layer').LayerConfig;

    export const FastLayer: typeof import('konva/lib/FastLayer').FastLayer;
    export type FastLayer = import('konva/lib/FastLayer').FastLayer;

    export const Group: typeof import('konva/lib/Group').Group;
    export type Group = import('konva/lib/Group').Group;

    export const DD: typeof import('konva/lib/DragAndDrop').DD;

    export const Shape: typeof import('konva/lib/Shape').Shape;
    export type Shape = import('konva/lib/Shape').Shape;
    export type ShapeConfig = import('konva/lib/Shape').ShapeConfig;
    export const shapes: typeof import('konva/lib/Shape').shapes;

    export const Animation: typeof import('konva/lib/Animation').Animation;
    export type Animation = import('konva/lib/Animation').Animation;

    export const Tween: typeof import('konva/lib/Tween').Tween;
    export type Tween = import('konva/lib/Tween').Tween;
    export type TweenConfig = import('konva/lib/Tween').TweenConfig;
    export const Easings: typeof import('konva/lib/Tween').Easings;

    export const Arc: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Arc').Arc;
    export type Arc = import('konva/lib/shapes/Arc').Arc;
    export type ArcConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Arc').ArcConfig;
    export const Arrow: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Arrow').Arrow;
    export type Arrow = import('konva/lib/shapes/Arrow').Arrow;
    export type ArrowConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Arrow').ArrowConfig;
    export const Circle: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Circle').Circle;
    export type Circle = import('konva/lib/shapes/Circle').Circle;
    export type CircleConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Circle').CircleConfig;
    export const Ellipse: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Ellipse').Ellipse;
    export type Ellipse = import('konva/lib/shapes/Ellipse').Ellipse;
    export type EllipseConfig =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/Ellipse').EllipseConfig;
    export const Image: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Image').Image;
    export type Image = import('konva/lib/shapes/Image').Image;
    export type ImageConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Image').ImageConfig;
    export const Label: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').Label;
    export type Label = import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').Label;
    export type LabelConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').LabelConfig;
    export const Tag: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').Tag;
    export type Tag = import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').Tag;
    export type TagConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Label').TagConfig;
    export const Line: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Line').Line;
    export type Line = import('konva/lib/shapes/Line').Line;
    export type LineConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Line').LineConfig;
    export const Path: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Path').Path;
    export type Path = import('konva/lib/shapes/Path').Path;
    export type PathConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Path').PathConfig;
    export const Rect: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Rect').Rect;
    export type Rect = import('konva/lib/shapes/Rect').Rect;
    export type RectConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Rect').RectConfig;
    export const RegularPolygon: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/RegularPolygon').RegularPolygon;
    export type RegularPolygon =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/RegularPolygon').RegularPolygon;
    export type RegularPolygonConfig =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/RegularPolygon').RegularPolygonConfig;
    export const Ring: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Ring').Ring;
    export type Ring = import('konva/lib/shapes/Ring').Ring;
    export type RingConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Ring').RingConfig;
    export const Sprite: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Sprite').Sprite;
    export type Sprite = import('konva/lib/shapes/Sprite').Sprite;
    export type SpriteConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Sprite').SpriteConfig;
    export const Star: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Star').Star;
    export type Star = import('konva/lib/shapes/Star').Star;
    export type StarConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Star').StarConfig;
    export const Text: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Text').Text;
    export type Text = import('konva/lib/shapes/Text').Text;
    export type TextConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Text').TextConfig;
    export const TextPath: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/TextPath').TextPath;
    export type TextPath = import('konva/lib/shapes/TextPath').TextPath;
    export type TextPathConfig =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/TextPath').TextPathConfig;
    export const Transformer: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Transformer').Transformer;
    export type Transformer =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/Transformer').Transformer;
    export type TransformerConfig =
      import('konva/lib/shapes/Transformer').TransformerConfig;
    export const Wedge: typeof import('konva/lib/shapes/Wedge').Wedge;
    export type Wedge = import('konva/lib/shapes/Wedge').Wedge;
    export type WedgeConfig = import('konva/lib/shapes/Wedge').WedgeConfig;

    export const Filters: {
      Blur: typeof Blur;
      Brighten: typeof Brighten;
      Contrast: typeof Contrast;
      Emboss: typeof Emboss;
      Enhance: typeof Enhance;
      Grayscale: typeof Grayscale;
      HSL: typeof HSL;
      HSV: typeof HSV;
      Invert: typeof Invert;
      Kaleidoscope: typeof Kaleidoscope;
      Mask: typeof Mask;
      Noise: typeof Noise;
      Pixelate: typeof Pixelate;
      Posterize: typeof Posterize;
      RGB: typeof RGB;
      RGBA: typeof RGBA;
      Sepia: typeof Sepia;
      Solarize: typeof Solarize;
      Threshold: typeof Threshold;
    };
  }
}
```

Then in your ts file:

```js
/// <reference path="./konva.d.ts" />

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: '',
});
```

Comment: Cannot tell you how appreciative I am. I'm not great at the typescript stuff outside of actually programming it. This has been sitting on my backburner for months. `declare global` ftw!